# Can't Find JS file in Console

Tags: html, jquery, console

I am pretty new and I am trying to work with the GIPHY API, but I can not get my js file to be found in the browser.  I have tried to create a whole new repo and I got the same issue.  Can anyone help?
Here is my directory:

[Image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7cdo.png)

Here is my HTML.  Can anyone Help?

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2NwM.png)

When I look in the console I get the message:Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

There is teh GIPHY sample code in the file so it is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the standard way, you should move your `index.html` file in the root of the project and then point your js file like this `js/main.js` instead of `js\main.js`

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what did the trick!  I appreciate the help!

Comment: @mthompson1085, your welcome, please mark the right answer if my suggestion helped you. it would also help other to find the right answer thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your path is not correct you need to point to the exact location your file is.

Try with `../js/main.js` instead of `js\main.js`

Answer (score 0):

If you can make your source to be just the file name like`main.js`alone
It will make you avoid the mistake of `js\main.js` thus solving the issue

Comment: main.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:6 GET file:///C:/Users/mthompson6/Documents/GitHub/Project2/html/js/giphy.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND